# How to add Anomalies in dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataset, anomaly-detection

I want to detect anomalies from continuous data set. The dataset is generated from `sklearn.datasets.samples_generator`

here is the code to generate dataset

```
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
(X,y) =  make_blobs(n_samples=100,n_features=5,centers=3,cluster_std=1.3,random_state=40)
```

Now, I want to add anomalies in that dataset and then I will detect these anomalies. I can detect anomalies I have code for that but first I need anomalies in that dataset.

Answer (score 1):

For all I know, there is no function in sklearn api that generates outliers.

But `make_blob` also accepts parameters in a more detailed manner in which you can specify number of samples for each cluster, "centers & standard deviation" for each feature. (`make_blob` uses a Gaussian distribution for generating datasets.)

The solution is to generate data in two steps, once for actual data & once for anomalies using different centers & standard deviation.

```
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=sample_list, centers=center_list, cluster_std=diviation_list,n_features=2,random_state=0)
```

In the above code, specify `sample_list` as an array of shape(1,#NumberOfClusters), `center_list` & `diviation_list` as an array of shape (#NumberofClusters,#NumberOfFeatures).